# Break on Column, Compute sum in postgres

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to transform an SQL query into Postgres, and i am struggling to do the below,

Example :

RESULTS FROM FIRST QUERY FOR MY NEXT QUERY : `select sourcename, type, count(type), sum(size) from table;`

```
 sourcename |                      Type                       | count |   sum
------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+----------
 A          | TYPE1                                           |    21 | 10485378
 B          | TYPE1                                           |    12 |  5241177
 C          | TYPE1                                           |    12 |  5242254
 D          | TYPE1                                           |    12 |  5570560
 A          | TYPE2                                           |    11 |  5239645
 B          | TYPE2                                           |    12 |  5570560
 C          | TYPE2                                           |    12 |  5241862
 D          | TYPE2                                           |    11 |  5570560
```

OUTPUT I NEED:

```
 sourcename |                      Type                       | count |   sum
------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------+----------
 A          | TYPE1                                           |    21 | 10485378
            | TYPE2                                           |    12 |  5241177
TOTAL       |                                                 |    33 | sum(values above)

 B          | TYPE1                                           |    12 |  5242254
            | TYPE2                                           |    12 |  5570560
TOTAL       |                                                 |    24 | sum(values above)

 C          | TYPE1                                           |    11 |  5239645
            | TYPE2                                           |    12 |  5570560
TOTAL       |                                                 |    23 | sum(values above)

 D          | TYPE1                                           |    12 |  5241862
            | TYPE2                                           |    11 |  5570560
TOTAL       |                                                 |    23 | sum(values above)
```

NOTE: I have used WITH AS to get the total but displaying them between each Source name i.e. A,B,C,D is something i am not able to do, i am also not able to suppress A from getting displayed twice in the results, like in oracle its break on sourcename, but is there a postgres equivalent?. also compute sum on column is in oracle , i could not find a postgres equivalent. I have finally found a way out using both shell and psql to get the below desired results, but i need to know if there is a better way to do this without using shell in between. Any help is much appreciated. I am using psql 9.1.3

I am new to this forum, so if you see my table results not aligned for viewing let me know, i will try to set it right.

(Using PostgreSQL 9.1)

Comment: This is actually quite hard to do in SQL. PostgreSQL 9.5 will make it easier using `WITH ROLLUP`, as part of the grouping sets support. For now, you need to do a union over the original query to produce the aggregates.

Comment: Hi Craig, Yes, i am currently using WITH AS, then select union select to display both results and aggregates, however i just wanted to know if there is a better way like a one liner command which im not aware of? I ask this because even for simple aggregate i have to use a WITH AS combo, so i will wait and see if i get any replies :) Thanks for your help.

Comment: Look up 9.5 grouping sets and WITH ROLLUP

Comment: Well Craig, i think i cant upgrade my postgres, so i broke the query and made views, from which i can further get the output i desire.